# Can I have one datasource for a table and a separate datasource for a details type view in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi

I am very new to PowerBI. I am trying to develop something where I display a list of records on a table with limited information (name, ID). When the user clicks on a row in the table, I would like to show more detailed information about the selected row. This more detailed information would come from another datasource.

For example, let's say there is a table populated by a datasource of customers. The datasource simply shows the first name, last name and ID. When that row is clicked, I would like to make a call to another datasource with the ID to retrieve all the customer details and display them.

If I was doing this in code, there would be some sort of event on the table that would fire when a row was changed/clicked, but I have no idea if this an option in PowerBI.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI doesn't work that way.

Instead you load both tables in their entirety, and then add a relationship between the two tables.

Alternatively, [Dynamic M query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters) might be what you are looking for.